# How do I edit an existing page for a client

Tags: html, dns

I have been given the login details to a client's domain name which is hosted by 1 & 1. I just need to know how I can pull the source code and edit again?

Comment: You just login via ftp and pull the source code.

Comment: There might be a CMS (Content Management System) like Drupal or Wordpress at work

Comment: There are **many** possibilities for how a website might be set up. How the DNS is configured is pretty much entirely irrelevant. We've no way of knowing what sort of set up your client has.

Answer (score 0):

At the Login of 1and1 you check the domains section. There you can see in the status columns, which folder is connected to the domain name.

You then need to check the users section (SFTP & SSH or the like) and you can set the password, if you don't know it already. Also there should be written the connection settings with your FTP-Program.

You can then connect with FTP (SFTP or SCP/SSH recommended) in your favourite FTP program (I recommend WinSCP on Windows; On Mac I don't know, maybe Cyberduck) to check.

There are two possibilities how the content is presented:
1. Static HTML pages. You see this, when your folder structure is the same as on the website
2. Dynamic pages (by PHP or another programming language). You see this normally, when there is a `index.ext` with `ext` being `php`, `rb` or the like; anything else than `html` or `htm`